# How to define Wakanda custom widget childrens?

Tags: javascript, wakanda

I'm creating a custom widget in Wakanda.

This widget must receive children. How could I alter this widget so that I can drop other widgets inside it?

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to contain widgets a custom widget using the version 2 of the API must inherit the *container behaviour*.

`YourWidget.inherit(WAF.require('waf-behavior/layout/container'));`

An example is the Container widget included in the WAF.

```
WAF.define('Container', ['waf-core/widget'], function(widget) {
  "use strict";

  var Container = widget.create('Container', {
    init: function() {
        this.removeClass('well well-sub');
        if($(this.node).closest('.well').length > 0){
            this.addClass('well-sub');
        }
        else{
            this.addClass('well');
        }
    }
  });
  Container.inherit(WAF.require('waf-behavior/layout/container'));

  return Container;
});
```

[Container widget source code](https://github.com/Wakanda/Container/tree/WAK11)

Answer (score 0):

Your widget should inherit from 'waf-behavior/layout/container' . 
This part of  documentation contains your need : http://livedoc.wakanda.org/Widgets-Instance-API/Container.201-1055278.en.html